# Remap one of the keyboards

Tags: keyboard, windows-10, remap

I have a notebook which sometimes I use with an external keyboard. Its built-in keyboard has some keys which I'd like to remap, however, I don't want to make any changes to the external keyboard.

I am aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13742630/can-you-remap-keys-of-a-specific-keyboard) question from 2012, but I'd like to have a different solution (a more user-friend one) if possible.

I use Win 10 on an Acer Aspire E 13.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [SharpKeys](http://sharpkeys.codeplex.com/) to remap any key you want. I also use Win 10 and it work verry nice. Don't forget to restart your computer after **Write to Registry**.
[image]

Comment: Nice way to test the result: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/javascript-keycodes/